# How do you type with typescript an destructured variable like const { company } = data?

Tags: typescript

How do I type this?

```
const { company }: CompanyType = data;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mqvJrW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.  *Maybe* you're looking for [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2KGrN)?  I just can't tell from the question because there's not a lot to go on. Help?

Comment: What is `CompanyType` and what is `data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type it like this:

```
const { company }: {company:CompanyType} = data;
```

This is equivalent to casting `data` to `{company:CompanyType}`, then destructure it.

```
const { company } = data as {company:CompanyType};
```

Comment: Is that equivalent? Type assertions allow unsafe things, so it really depends on what `data` is.